# Git SSH key not being found

Tags: git, ssh, repository, git-bash

I'm trying to push my source up to our local Git repo. I've created an id_rsa key and added the key to GitLab, and a config file with the following contents:

```
Host git@git.repo.local
 IdentityFile H:\.ssh\id_rsa
```

When I enter the following push command in Git Bash I receive a `Could not read from remote repository.` error:

```
$ git push git@git.repo.local:android/myApp.git
```

This was previously working fine when I was working from my C: drive but now I am working on a server drive (H:) it does not seem to like it.

Am I missing some set up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing this in your config file:

```
Host git.repo.local
 IdentityFile H:\.ssh\id_rsa
```